# How to know the number of different ID for a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table :

```
TAILLE_ID    | TAILLE_LIBELLE
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
32           | CHAUSSURES
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
32           | CHAUSSURES
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
837          | CHAUSSURES
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

I would like to know the number of different ID for "CHAUSSURES" (2 in this case)

What kind of query could be that ?

Comment: `count(distinct TAILLE_ID)`

Comment: Without a PRIMARY KEY, I'd argue that you don't really have a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TAILLLE_ID) FROM Table_Name WHERE TAILLE_LIBELLE = 'CHAUSSURES';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `count(distinct)`:

```
select TAILLE_LIBELLE, count(distinct TAILLE_ID)
from t
group by TAILLE_LIBELLE;
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful !